# Microsoft SQL Server Syntax Error

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can someone please help resolve the syntax error for the below query? Thank you so much!

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
Incorrect syntax near ')'.

```
    with cte_EOMDenials as
    (select d.* from rrscsql2.Denials.dbo.tblDenialMonthEnd d --Pulls LP Denials EOM detail
    Inner join rrscsql3.Facilities.dbo.vwFacilities f
    on d.UnitNum = f.UnitNum and f.Owner like '%LifePoint%'
    Inner join rrscsql2.Denials.dbo.tblDispositionDictionary t
    on d.disposition=t.disposition and DispositionType like'O%'
    Where datediff(mm, monthending, GETDATE()) = 1
    and DATEDIFF(mm,DischDate,monthending)>2))
```

Comment: Programming languages and/or products belong in the tags, not the title. Unfortunately, if I remove "Microsoft SQL Server" from the title, we just get "Syntax error" which is far too vague.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
;with cte_EOMDenials as
    (select d.* from rrscsql2.Denials.dbo.tblDenialMonthEnd d --Pulls LP Denials EOM detail
    Inner join rrscsql3.Facilities.dbo.vwFacilities f
    on d.UnitNum = f.UnitNum and f.Owner like '%LifePoint%'
    Inner join rrscsql2.Denials.dbo.tblDispositionDictionary t
    on d.disposition=t.disposition and DispositionType like'O%'
    Where datediff(mm, monthending, GETDATE()) = 1
    and DATEDIFF(mm,DischDate,monthending)>2)


select * from cte_EOMDenials
```

Comment: Thank you so much, easy fix but needed your help! Appreciate it very much!

Comment: pls do accept by clicking left tick mark !

Comment: Looks like I have to wait 8 minutes, but I will.